# jQuery code working everywhere but IE, why?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

The following code works fine in browsers other than IE. In IE, only the #toggle-instructions handler works, but #toggle-cue-sheet-instructions does not. Anyone know why IE has trouble with this? What happens is that clicking on the link with id=toggle-cue-sheet-instructions does nothing while clicking on the link with id=toggle-instructions works fine. I tried toggle, but, if I recall correctly, I had an issue with it in one of the browsers and went this route instead (which isn't my preference). Everything works perfectly in Safari and Firefox (what else is new right?).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#toggle-instructions").click(function() {
    if ($("#download-items #instructions").is(":hidden")) {
      $("#download-items .instructions-link a").text("Hide download instructions");
      $("#download-items #instructions").slideDown("slow");
    }
    else {
      $("#download-items .instructions-link a").text("View download instructions");
      $("#download-items #instructions").slideUp("normal");
    }
    return false;
  });
  $("#toggle-cue-sheet-instructions").click(function() {
    if ($("#prs-info-container #instructions").is(":hidden")) {
      $("#prs-info-container .instructions-link a").text("Hide cue sheet instructions");
      $("#prs-info-container #instructions").slideDown("slow");
    }
    else {
      $("#prs-info-container .instructions-link a").text("View cue sheet instructions");
      $("#prs-info-container #instructions").slideUp("normal");
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: You should really be using the toggle() method.

Comment: What is the intent of the code? what is happening in IE that makes you think it doesn't work? are there any error messages? help us help you

Comment: m79. You have to be more specific about the problem itself!

Comment: Thanks for responding. I updated the description of the problem. Pls let me know if it is still not clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code, it appears as though you are using the `instructions` ID more than once.

If that's the case, you need to change your HTML markup so you're not reusing an ID more than once. IDs on a page *must be unique*.

It is these two lines that cause me to think that you are reusing `instructions` as an ID

```
  $("#download-items #instructions").slideDown("slow");
  ...
  $("#prs-info-container #instructions").slideDown("slow");
```

If you try to select using an ID that is not unique, things will break.

Generally the solution is to use a class instead of an ID if you need/want to have multiple.

This is what those two lines would look like if `instructions` was a class.

```
  $("#download-items .instructions").slideDown("slow");
  ...
  $("#prs-info-container .instructions").slideDown("slow");
```

Now [the `.` class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) is used instead of [the `#` ID selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/).

Of course you'll need to change your HTML markup as well to use `class="instructions"` instead of `id="instructions"`.

Comment: I agree, I came to the same conclusion (unless the OP moves/recycles the same `#instructions` element throughout the page). IE probably either ignores the second ID completely when processing the code (so the second selector never make a match), or it halts JS processing when jQuery attempts to access the element (potentionally by getElementsById).

Comment: patrick dw: thanks man! another set of eyes really helps. good job catching that, appreciate it.

Comment: @MicE - Yeah, the results are never predictable when reusing IDs. The reason it worked in FF and Safari could have to do with the fact that both (in the most recent versions) have `querySelectorAll` that Sizzle tries to use before anything else. But who knows. :o)